# Finding the bug in my tree level widths algorithm in es6

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6, tree

I'm practicing solving an algorithmic problem and need help finding the bug in my code.

--- Directions
Given the root node of a tree, return
an array where each element is the width
of the tree at each level.

I've tried running tests cases on it and as well running it in JSBin but no luck. Getting this error when running test:  TypeError: undefined is not iterable

```
// my node class
class Node {
    constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.children = [];
    }

    add(data) {
        this.children.push(new Node(data));
    }
};

function levelWidth(root) {
    const store = [];
    const widths = [0];
    if(root){
        store.push(root);
        store.push('stop');
    }
    while(store.length > 1){
        const value = store.shift();
        if(value === 'stop'){
            widths.push(0);
            store.push(stop);
        }
        else {
            store.push(...value.children);
            widths[widths.length - 1]++;
        }
  }
  return widths;
}
```

When running

```
    expect(levelWidth(root)).toEqual([1, 3, 2]);
```

I expect to get an array of [1,3,2] but instead get TypeError: undefined is not iterable for

```
    store.push(...value.children);
```

From what I can see I'm using the spread operator correctly?

Comment: `stop` is undefined e.g., when you typed `store.push(stop);`.

Comment: Yes!  Stop is supposed to be 'stop'. It's a marker to indicate when the end of a level has been reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current bug is being caused because the variable `stop` is not defined; i.e., your expression `store.push(stop);` references an undefined variable `stop`.

Comment out that line and that *particular* bug is no longer an issue:

```
// my node class
class Node {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.children = [];
  }

  add (data) {
    this.children.push(new Node(data));
  }
};

function levelWidth (root) {
  const store = [];
  const widths = [0];
  if (root) {
    store.push(root);
    store.push('stop');
  }
  while (store.length > 1) {
    const value = store.shift();
    if (value === 'stop') {
      widths.push(0);
      // store.push(stop);
    }
    else {
      store.push(...value.children);
      widths[widths.length - 1]++;
    }
  }
  return widths;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  The old "forgot the quotes around my value". My test cases are passing now.